# How to Actually change PHP Version that used by composer?

Tags: php, laravel-5, xampp, composer-php

I'm quite new to this composer and laravel stuff, and I'm using **XAMPP** in **Windows 10**..
so, sorry if I missed something.

At first I Install my composer on my windows, and I'm using **PHP V.5.6** as default php engine on my composer, for starter i could develop my **laravel** project normally, atleast until **Laravel V.5.4**..

but now i have install other **XAMPP with PHP V.7.1** ("in Partition") and when I try to developing **Laravel V.5.5** app, I couldn't develop my new **Laravel** App freely, because my composer still running on **PHP V.5.6**. For some reason I need both of my **PHP version**, and I still couldn't figure out a way to switch between **PHP Engine** that used by the **Composer**..

**So, My Question is**.
Is there any simple way to change PHP Version used by composer without install/uninstalling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know how do you run the composer script so my answer can be useless for you.

You have two different versions of php, so you have two binary files for each version, so you can use needed binary file to run the composer from your command line:

```
$ /path/to/needed/binary/php composer.phar install
```

But it can be a really bad idea. Libraries in the composer can depend of others and those can depend from php version. Your composer loads libraries which are relying on php version wich is currently running. So it can load libraries which will not work in other php version.

Comment: Isn't that'll only work for composer function..? yet it wouldnt change the default of php engine on composer..? For example I have composer with **PHP V5.6.** Then I try to run Artisan function in **laravel V5.5** still it would give me an error like "Syntax error, unexpected '?' in" an error that usually shown up in laravel V.5.5 with php V.5.6...

Comment: what will this `composer.phar install` script do to composer.. @marv255

Comment: I think that I don't understand you right. Do you want to set php version by composer and this version will be used by your app? The way I offered will only change php version for composer script and nothing else. If you want to manage multiple projects with multiple php versions you better try [docker](https://github.com/laradock/laradock) or [vagrant](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead).

Answer (score 0):

IFAIK, you cannot do that with built-in composer functionality.

But if you **really** want to manage PHP version with with composer you can use pre-install-cmd hook in order to switch the default PHP version using, for example PHPenv.

And yes, IMHO, XAMPP is not the best development env. I see that you use Laravel, have you tried Homestead?

Comment: Actually I haven't tried to use homestead.. I guess I'll try to learn it soon.. and I'm not too familliar with pre-installed-cmd hook.. is by using it I'll be able to change PHP V freely..?

Comment: pre-installed-cmd you can run any command you want. default PHP version can be changed by PHPenv command.